# sql как сделать условие where для поля/ей с указанным псевдонимом

Tags: sql, база-данных

Как коректно задать условие where для полей name_1 и name_2

```
select temp."ZavKod", left(temp."Склад_1С", 2) as name_1, left(temp."Склад_ПО", 2) as name_2
from (select *
      from temp_table_xxx
      where "Склад_ПО" not like "Склад_1С") as temp;
-- where name_1 not like name_2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

чаще всего бд не поддерживают такие обращения к алиасам (например, оракл и майкрософт sql), поэтому в условии where нужно повторить колонки, которые были обозначены алиасами

Comment: Спасибо ! :)  ...